# Reading fixed-layout ePubs

Tags: ebook-reader, epub

I'm looking for a way to read fixed-layout ePubs; nothing I've found supports this format.
Aldiko supports epub, but surely not a fixed-layout epub.

Is there a possibility here to have the same support here that we have on iOS?

Comment: Did you try [Moon+ Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flyersoft.moonreader)? It has a "preview with publisher format" option, which could work for your case.

Comment: Damn… there is the point on every android ebooks apps I could find : Is there one that follows the epubs spec (which in that case is not the publisher format) ? Or do they all try to set their random format ?